# Stateless Session Bean with Local / Remote Interface

Tags: session, interface, ejb, local, stateless-session-bean

I am trying to understand the implementation difference between creating a local or remote interface for my stateless session bean however I see various solutions and am wondering if there is a certain "standard" or general "preference".

For local interface, I can create everything (servlets, session bean, jsp) within a Java EE Enterprise Application project.

For remote interface, do I need to create the remote interface in a Java Class Library or Java Application or Java Web Application? Then the remaining code is within a Java EE Enterprise Application project...

Also, what is the reason for creating a session bean in a Java EE Enterprise Application Project instead of a Java Web Application Project?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to understand the implementation difference between
>   creating a local or remote interface for my stateless session bean
>   however I see various solutions and am wondering if there is a certain
>   "standard" or general "preference".

The main difference is that remote interface are coarse grained and the call is by value. While local interface are fine grained and the call is by reference.

> For remote interface, do I need to create the remote interface in a
>   Java Class Library or Java Application or Java Web Application? Then
>   the remaining code is within a Java EE Enterprise Application
>   project...

if you have a remote interface, it has to be packed in a separate .jar file. The .jar file has then to be included as a dependency in your main project (on the application server) and distributed to your remote client.

> Also, what is the reason for creating a session bean in a Java EE
>   Enterprise Application Project instead of a Java Web Application
>   Project?

Since ejb 3.1 specification, an ejb can be packed directly in a .war file.
In the old J2EE days an ejb could only be packed in a .jar to be included in a .ear file.